# (2+2)-dimensional flat spacetime with neutral signature

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, time, metric-tensor, spacetime-dimensions

Is there an example of (2+2)-dimensional flat spacetime with neutral signature (i.e. (+,+,-,-))? 
...for example the metric $ds^2=(dt_1)^2+(dt_2)^2-(dx)^2-(dy)^2$,  has been studied? Are there any papers in this regard in the literature (i.e. I mean where the authors consider also the flat case)

EDITED  QUESTION

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/43322/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/43630/2451, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/19802/2451  and links therein.

Comment: This seems very similar to [More than one time dimension](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/43630/more-than-one-time-dimension). The only difference is that you mention a flat geometry. Could you clarify why a flat spacetime should be special and not covered by the previous question?

Comment: I am interested in knowing if (2+2)-dimensional flat spacetime with neutral signature  has been studied and if there are any works in this regard in the literature