# Is the dimensionality of space considered a universal constant?

Tags: spacetime, dimensional-analysis, spacetime-dimensions

What if the dimensionality was something like 3.0001 or 2.999? Would we be able to tell the difference? I heard about fractional dimensionality in 3b1b and was wondering about its implications for physics

Comment: could you point to the source?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/19802/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Could you define what you mean by a fractional dimension here? Space is usually considered as a manifold, for which only integer dimensions are defined.

Answer (score 0):

The dimensionality of spacetime affects how forces spread out. Gravity and EM radiation decline as $1/r^{D-1}$. This has observable effects, for example that only in $D=3$ will orbits close ([Bertrand's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_theorem)) and [how the wave equation allows information to spread](https://arxiv.org/abs/1505.05855). I have not seen estimates, but given that light from remote quasars still remain undispersed $D$ must be close to 3.