# Higher dimension world possibility

Tags: spacetime, universe, spacetime-dimensions, branes

Could it be possible that all of the unexplained phenomena (like uncertainty)  in our 4D world might be originated from a higher dimension universe? If so, then of course we'll never observe the actual phenomena since we only live in a lower dimension world. For people who live in higher dimension universe, all that is uncertain for us, is deterministic for them.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/35644/

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/10651/2451 and links therein.