# If gravitation force varied with $r^{-3}$ instead of $r^{-2}$ what would happen to Kepler's laws

Tags: forces, classical-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion

2nd law wouldn't change as it is LCAM. 3rd Law would change. But I'm confused about first law. Does any body under influence of any central force move in an ellipse?Can anyone give a simple proof/explanation?

Comment: The idea of an inverse-cube law for conventional spherical planets is un-physical in the first place: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/47084

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: (v2) I don't think the edit changes much: you've removed the direct contradiction of words, but the meaning remains: because we're considering points/spheres which don't produce inverse-square gravitational fields, we have a situation in which some more fundamental principles don't apply.

Comment: Will it move in an ellipse?

Comment: I think this is an interesting question even though it does not apply to planetary systems. Please respect the name of the scientist and also use latex style formulas , such as $r^{-3}$.