# Why the force is inversly proportional to the square of distance?

Tags: electromagnetism, newtonian-gravity, gauss-law, spacetime-dimensions, coulombs-law

Lesser the distance higher the force of attraction.but why it is the square of distance?And also the reason i guess for this force is the attraction force between atoms ( electrons of one atom and proton of the other) . But when the distance become  lesser and lesser,the repulsive force will overcome the attractive force isnt it?Then wont the attractive force decrease?

Comment: what repulsive force?

Comment: This explains the inverse square law; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-square_law

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are so many forces explainable using inverse squares when space is three dimensional?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/47084/)