# Why is the distance between two objects is squared in the definition of Gravitational Force?

Tags: forces, newtonian-gravity, gauss-law, distance

In the definition of the Newton's Law of Universal Gravitation, the gravitational force between two bodies is directly proportional to the product of masses of the objects and inversely proportional to the square of distance between them, My question is that why is the distance squared? SO far form what i know, i assume the reason to be, In a three dimensional space, the surface area of a sphere is directly proportional to the square of its radius, thus in a system of a point mass and a sphere, the gravitational force experienced by the sphere should be inversely proportional to it's surface area, as when we increase the distance between them, the Gravitational force decreases, and the gravitational force is uniform across the surface of the sphere and thus ultimately the Gravitational force is inversely proportional to the surface area of the sphere, where the surface area of the sphere is directly proportional to its radius, Man but this reason is not satisfactory! Can someone help we redefine the above reason?

I was navigated to a thread from this post: [Why are so many forces explainable using inverse squares when space is three dimensional?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/47084/)

which partially answers my question, but if any one had the same doubt, you can surely check this thread!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are so many forces explainable using inverse squares when space is three dimensional?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/47084/)

Comment: Fundamentally the reason is because this is what matches experiment - theoretical reasons are basically 'sugar' on top of the empirical facts.

Comment: Related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_law_for_gravity