# What if interactions such as gravity faded with respect to the cube of distance, rather than square?

Tags: gravity, interactions

It's generally understood that anything that "spreads out" in 3D space dissipates at a rate proportional to the square of distance. Light, sound, gravitational force, etc. I know this is a pretty fixed rate due to geometry.

A thought I can't get out of my head, though: What if it somehow made since for this rate to be cubic? What if doubling the distance didn't make an interaction one fourth as strong, but one eight, etc? Particularly gravity on a cosmic scale.

Apologies if this question is too broad, but I couldn't think of a better place to ask it.

Comment: See this [related question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/47084/104402)  and links therein.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A change in the gravitational law](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/41109/)