# Higher dimensions

Tags: spacetime, spacetime-dimensions

1) How we determine whether the higher dimensions are  Unstable or Unpredictable? Or on the basis of what assumption we make this prediction?

[image: Dimensions]

(Source of Image: [Max Tegmark](http://space.mit.edu/home/tegmark/dimensions.html). See also [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spacetime#Privileged_character_of_3.2B1_spacetime) Wikipedia article.)

Comment: The diagram is taken from the [Max Tegmark reference](http://space.mit.edu/home/tegmark/dimensions.pdf) in your linked wikipedia article.  In it Tegmark explains how he came to those conclusions.

Comment: @twistor59: Thanks. Updated the question accordingly.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/10651/2451