# Arguments for the dimension of space

Tags: spacetime, spacetime-dimensions

I would like to collect arguments whose conclusion indicate that the dimension of space cannot be anything.

For example, the existence of non-trivial knots implies that the dimension of space is $3$ (since in dimension $1$, there are no knots, in dimension $2$, they are all circles by Jordan's theorem, and in dimension $4$, they are all isotopic to circles since there is enough room to unentangle any curve).

As another example, a radial, divergence-free vector field on $\mathbb{R}^n \setminus \{0\}$ is proportional to $x \mapsto \frac{x}{\vert x \vert^{n}}$; so if the gravitational field created by a point mass is physically supposed to be divergence-free and to have some form, then the dimension of space has to be $3$.

As a kind of a joke, a teacher once told me that in dimension $2$, living beings like us could not exist, since their digestive tubes would disconnect their bodies.

I know that some developments of string theory lead to results like this, but I would expect more elementary examples.

Comment: The "joke" you quoted [excludes a specific digestive strategy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2n7EBkz1BDM). Are you interested in [other anthropic arguments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anthropic_principle#Dimensions_of_spacetime)?

Comment: As for the detail you can't remember, $\nabla\cdot\frac{x}{|x|^m}=\frac{n-m}{|x|^m}$ (the proof is an easy exercise), which is $0$ iff $n=m$.

Comment: [_The Planiverse_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Planiverse) describes a method where "zipper muscles" attach and detach to pass fluids and nutrients around inside the bodies of organisms, though the digestive systems have a single opening.

Comment: Thank you very much for the links and for the reminder of the exponent for the divergence-free field. I'll wait for other reactions!

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/10651/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/110876/2451 and links therein.