# Why are we in 3 spatial dimensions?

Tags: cosmology, spacetime, universe, spacetime-dimensions

I am very curious to find if there is any reason that why are we in 3 dimensions not in any other like 1D would be hard almost impossible but 2D could have been possible, or what about 4D or in additional dimensions?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/10651/2451 and links therein.